# A question on measures/densities

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $Q,P,\nu$ be three measures on the same space such that $P\ll Q,P\ll\nu,Q\ll\nu$. Define $p=\frac{dP}{d\nu},q=\frac{dQ}{d\nu}$. Then $$\frac{1}{2}\int|p-q|d\nu=1-\int\min\{p,q\}d\nu$$
This should be almost obvious, but I don't see it. How can we show it?

Comment: $<<$ $\to$ `\ll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given two numbers $x,y$ it is known that
$$
\min\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}
$$
If you replace $p$ and $q$ in the formula your formula follows (after an integration with respect to $\nu$ and assuming that $P$ and $Q$ are probability measures).